# How do I use the slice javascript function to inject a string into a form field

Tags: javascript, variables, pdf

I'm not an advanced programmer, but I've learned some basic stuff in order to customize some PDF documents that are used in a third party web app.  It basically takes an XML stream from a mainframe and populates fields in the form.  The mainframe is currently sending over data for a zip code +4 field incorrectly.  It's adding a second "+4" string.  For example, if the string should be 12345-6789, it's coming over as 12345-6789-6789.

**What I need to do is strip the last 5 characters** from that data and place it in a field.  Below is what I have, and it's not working

```
var badcsz = this.getField("CSZ_FROM_MAINFRAME");//XMLDATA FROM MAINFRAME "CSZ_FROM_MAINFRAME"
var csz = this.getField("CORRECT_CSZ");//CORRECT_CSZ IS THE FIELD IN THE PDF
csz.value = badcsz.slice(0,-5);//
```

Answer (score 0):

```
csz.value = badcsz.slice(0, badcsz.length-5);
```

Answer (score 0):

With a regex can write a safer "remove last 5 chars" routine by using

```
csz.value = badcsz.replace(/(-\d{4})-\d{4}$/,'$1');
```

This has the benefit of not just always removing the last 5 chars, but will only remove the last 5 chars if they match the pattern: '-' followed by 4 digits (twice).